# ggplot2 legends: Adding items not in plot code to the legend & changing shapes in legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have a complex plot that shows dots of different colors for patient grades in different years, and lines of different colors connecting repeated measures (the same patients) measured in the two years whose grading has changed. As you can see the legend simply lists the dots with lines for the two colors. What I need, however, is a legend that has a red dot for 2009 and a blue dot for 2016 (without lines!), as well as a red line that I can label "Upgraded" and a blue line I can label "Downgraded". So I need four legend items: 2 dots, 2 lines, 4 labels. I've done extensive searching on this, and cannot find the answer.

Here's the plot code I used to build all the aesthetics I wanted:

```
sampledata <- structure(list(patient = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 19L), grade = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("grade_I", 
"grade_II", "grade_III", "indeterminate", "normal"), class = "factor"), 
year = c(2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 
2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 
2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 
2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L, 
2009L, 2016L, 2009L, 2016L)), .Names = c("patient", "grade", 
"year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -38L))

yearf = factor(year)

gradef = factor(gradef, levels=c("normal", "grade_I", "grade_II", "grade_III", "indeterminate"))

p <- ggplot(data=guidegrades2, aes(x=gradef, y=patient, group=patient, color=yearf)) + 
    geom_point() + geom_line()
p + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    labs(x = "ASE Grade", y = "Patient", color = "ASE Guidelines")

pticks = p + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("grade_I" = "Grade I", "grade_II" = "Grade II",
    "grade_III" = "Grade III", "indeterminate" = "Indeterminate", "normal" = "Normal"))

ptheme = pticks + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"), axis.line = element_line(), axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=0.0001)) 

paxes = ptheme + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    labs(x = "ASE Grade", y = "Patient", color = "ASE Guidelines")
```

[image: The plot in question]

Comment: Hard to be certain without seeing your data, but it looks like one option might be the following: First, use a point marker with separate border and fill colors. To do this, remove `color=yearf` from the main ggplot call and then  do `geom_point(shape=21, aes(fill=yearf))`. This will give you a filled circle as the point marker and a point legend without lines.

Comment: Next, you need to create a new column, let's call it `grade_change` in your data that marks each patient as "Upgraded" or "Downgraded". Then you can do `geom_line(aes(colour=grade_change))`. However, this might work better as a linetype (i.e., `linetype=grade_change`) than as a color since you already use color for the point marker. Or, you could use shape for the points and color for the lines.